# Fill form with checkbox array

Tags: php, curl

I want to create a PHP script which can fill up a form from a text file. The form is on a password-protected page. There are 4 fields where i need to put text (name, village, etc.)

I need to select checkboxes but they are in an array and I only know their label name. At max I can look up id's and use it as static values, but I don't know them how to use them either.

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
   <input type="checkbox" name="tag_id[]" id="tag_id_192" value="192"><label for="tag_id_192">House</label>
```

I saw lots of tutorials which shows how to do it with checkboxes but they used the check box name and without the login part. I never used PHP before so I don't know even where to start. If someone could guide i would be very grateful.

**Example:**
The .txt file each row represents a form fill up the fields are separated with a *: Name * village *..*.. * the check boxes label names which i need to set active

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cURL, you can post multiple fields with the same name, if it has [] after the name, php will automatically concatenate them all into an array..

So its valid to do tag_id[]=192&tag_id[]=175&tag_id=[285]..

In PHP it will know to make it array(192,175,285)

As a side note, fields that do not have [] get overwritten each time they appear...

Comment: so, if i do something like this:
$data = array(
    'name' => 'test',
    'k' => '999',
    'f' => '10',
 'l' => '10',
 'tag_id[]' => '190',
 
);
and use curl to post somehow.... should work ?

Comment: Then tag_id will equal array(192) in php...  If you do tag_id more than once, then the values will be appended onto the array in PHP....